# Centering a div with css in nextjs (moves but doesn't completely center)

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, next.js

I have tried looking at many questions on StackOverflow and none of them have helped me. I think that I have a more specific problem, there might be some type of CSS attribute that is stopping the div from centering. Maybe I need to use flexbox to solve this?

here is the JSX:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/login.module.css'

import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Login() {
    const [loginDetails, setLoginDetails] = useState({username: "", password: ""});

    function handleUsernameChange(e) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        setLoginDetails({username: value, password: loginDetails.password});
    }

    function handlePasswordChange(e) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        setLoginDetails({username: loginDetails.username, password: value});
    }

    function SubmitLogin() {
        console.log(loginDetails);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Login</title>
            </Head>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <h1 className={styles.subheading}>Login</h1>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" className={styles.input} onChange={handleUsernameChange} />
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" className={styles.input} onChange={handlePasswordChange} />
                <button className={styles.button} onClick={SubmitLogin}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.heading {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.subheading {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.pheading {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.paragraph {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
    
}
.input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #d7dbd9;
}

.input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #67f0ab;  
}

.button {
    border: 2px solid #67f0ab;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #67f0ab;
    background: none;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #67f0ab;
    color: #FFF;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #49de93;
}
```

The element I am trying to center is the div wrapping the login form. It has the class of `.container`, this class is what I was editing in my CSS to try and solve the problem. I can get the element to move to different spots, but I can't center it.

Comment: Note that the `margin: 0 auto` will be relative to the parent. I mean, if parent element is not 100% width, it won't be centered on the middle of the screen.

Comment: When I change it to 100% width, it moves all the way to the margin of the page.

Comment: did you apply the width 100% to parent or `.container`?

Comment: I tried parent and container and the only thing that changed is when I apply it to either, the div moves all the way to the left margin of the page.

Comment: @ask4you I figured it out and answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what the problem was, it was that the max-width of my container was larger than that of my widest element inside of the container, in this case it happened to be the inputs

I changed the `max-width` value of my container to `200px` which is the same as my `.input` class, and the container and all of its elements were then centered.